# Remove decimal point from currency using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a currency values range getting from json data as like below format:
$25,000-$35,000. It is getting displayed as like in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE9 and IE10 browser displaying like "$25,000.00-$35,000.00".

Wanted to remove those zeros after dots on IE browser. I have tried the below Regex:

```
s.replace(/(\.[0-9]*?)0+$/, "");
```

but got an output like:

```
"$25,000.00-$35,000"
```

Only removing on the end of the value. Please let me know what's wrong with the regex? Please help me out to resolve the issue.

Comment: `Only removing on the end of the value` - that's what the `$` in your regex does

Comment: ... and that is why you need to remove `$` and add `g` modifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I'd agree, but what if the value isn't `.00` but `.01` for example :p

Comment: basically, you only want to remove . if it's followed by 2 zeros ... so that should help make things very easy

Comment: @JaromandaX: I have already answered a question like this for Java some months ago. That is possible with regex, but looks ugly.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for pointing out. You can try following regex: `/\.\d+/g`. [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/p287cvky/)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/CQsJO9/2  try this `(\.[0-9]*?)(\d+)`

Comment: Try `.replace(/(\.\d*?)0+\b(?!\.\d)/g, "$1")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var s="$25,000.00-$35,000.00";
s=s.replace(/(\.[0-9]*?)0+/g, "");
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on weither or not there might be other things than 0 after the dot and how many there can be :

- `/\.(.*?[0]*)/g` : remove the dot and all following zeros
- `/\.(.*?[0]{1,2})/g` : remove the dot and the following 1 or 2 following zeros
- `/\.(.*?[0-9]*)/g` or `/\.(.*?\d*)/g` : remove the dot and the following numbers
- `/\.(.*?[0-9]{1,2})/g` or `/\.(.*?\d*)/g` : remove the dot and the following 1 or 2 numbers

Hope this helps

Comment: super detailed, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `$` marks the end of the text. You can remove it from your regular expression. But then, it will fail when the end of the text is `.01`.

You should find for the value and then only pick the dollar sign and the number without the decimal.

```js
s.replace(/(\$[0-9,]+)\.[0-9]+/, "$1");
```

`(\$[0-9,]+)` matches the dollar sign and the thousands separator (`,`), also save them as the first group match.

`\.[0-9]+` matches the decimals.

`"$1"` replace the text with the first group.

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it always has 0s after the dot you can use: `/\.0+/g`